# $\Bbb{R}$ with a given subbasis

Tags: general-topology

Let us consider $\Bbb{R}$ with topology $\tau$ generated by subbasis consisting of $\Bbb{Q}$ and all open intervals $(a,b)$.

Let $U$ be an open set in $(\Bbb{R},\tau)$ such that $U \subset \Bbb{Q}$

Then how can I show that there exists an open set $V$ in $(\Bbb{R},usual)$ such that $U = V \cap \Bbb{Q}$?

If $U$ is empty or $\Bbb{Q}$, then we are done.

What about the rest of the cases?

Answer (score 1):

1. For every point in $U$, find its open basic neighborhood in $\mathbb R^\dagger$ (that's what I will call your topology for the moment) which is also contained in $U$ (and hence in $\mathbb Q$).
2. This neighborhood is a finite intersection of some subbasis sets of $\mathbb R^\dagger$.
3. One of these sets is $\mathbb Q$, otherwise the said neighborhood would be an intersection of subbasis sets of usual $\mathbb R$, and hence contain some open interval of $\mathbb R$, and hence also contain some irrational point(s), which in fact it doesn't.
4. The intersection of the *rest of* the mentioned subbasis sets is an open set in usual $\mathbb R$...

...see where this is going?

Comment: From here, I am getting that there exists an open set $V$  in ($\Bbb{R}$,usual)(I am considering V to be intersection of some particular subbasic open sets) such that $\Bbb{Q} \cap V \subset U$. How do I show the other inclusion?

Comment: The problem is that if I consider V to be intersection of those subbasic open sets, then this V may be different for different elements in U. Hence I am facing a problem in getting the other inclusion.

Comment: Why, just take a union of all those V for all points of U. The union is open, as is any union of open sets. Also, its intersection with Q is contained in U and contains every point of U.